# Bundler can't find Ruby gem that appears on website

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I installed Bundler on a pre-Rails 3 application and am trying to use it to install gems. My Gemfile contains the following lines:

```
source :rubygems
[...]
gem "RubyInline", "3.8.1"
```

However, when I run `bundle install` I get this error:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'RubyInline', required by 'memcache-client (= 1.6.3)', in any of the sources
```

The gem appears on the rubygems website:

http://rubygems.org/gems/RubyInline

Why is it giving me an error then?

Comment: Could you post the entire Gemfile? It seems like it thinks memcache-client requires 'RubyInline', but looking at the gem it doesn't seem to have any dependencies at all.

Comment: It worked for me.  Try (gem sources -a http://gems.github.com)

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Which version of `bundler` are you using and what does you `Gemfile` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this resolved itself after changes to fix other issues, and I'm not sure what the fix was. The source of several other issues was wrong permissions on various gems/binaries.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue for me seems to be resolved on occasion by applying

```
bundle update
```

before

```
bundle install
```

The effect is to resolve old dependencies from when the bundle was originally produced and hence a gem that has been superseded (or whatever) will no longer be in the Gemfile.